# Help understanding underlying reason of oom-killer kicking in

Tags: kernel, 20.04, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 fully up-to-date with a Raspberry Pi 4, 4GB of RAM (may be relevant or not, but system is running with an SSD through an USB3.0 port) as a low-power PC capable of running some Docker images. It runs xfce4 displaying a Magic Mirror, and it recollects some data through the GPIO ports (which takes only a few mA): power supply is an original 3A power adapter.

The problem I'm having is that today it lost the ethernet connection but the rpi itself kept on running just fine... until I plugged in a keyboard at which point it just kernel panicked or so. No logging at that point available to know what happened there.

When I checked out the journal, the following caught my attention:
https://pastebin.com/0VNDSUyL

At the time, memory usage was about 90% according to the latest data available (I run Telegraf and log everything to an Influxdb instance running [both with Docker] on the same machine).

The process that was killed was Java, but I don't know which Docker image it was because the runtime isn't even installed on the host.

- Is this an indicator that I am running low on RAM? What can I do to avoid this problem in the future?
- Why did the OOM-killer kicked in while I still had about 10% of RAM left? Is this tweakable?
- Why did it kill my ethernet connection? Did it left the system in an unstable condition?
- Can it be something hardware related that is creating this issue?

I don't know where to look further atm, so any help here would be very much appreciated! If you need more details, just ask :)

**EDIT1:**

I have no swap enabled on this system:

```
ubuntu@unifi:~ $ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       2.7Gi       190Mi       203Mi       826Mi       886Mi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
ubuntu@unifi:~ $ grep -i swap /etc/fstab 
ubuntu@unifi:~ $
```

Comment: Do you have a /swapfile on this computer? It looks like not. Memory is full and no place to swap. Boom. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Hi @heynnema thanks for answering! I have no swap configured so that might just be it :) Totally forgot about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create the missing /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```